# Normalizing logistic regression probabilities to fixed number

Tags: regression, logistic

I have run a logistic regression model on a target variable and get a list of probabilities like [0.50, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01].

For the target situation, I know that there are always going to be 3 positive results. I’m looking at a soccer league and comparing some stats (goals, last year rank, etc) to predict likelihood of top 3 in a given year. Each previous subgroup/year will have 3 positive results.  However, since the probabilities calculated are independent of each other, the predicted values for a next year’s group will not sum to 3. Since I know the group of teams for this year, I would want the sum of the predicted values to equal my target of 3.

I'm wondering if there is a way to properly scale/adjust these probabilities so that they add up to 3, obviously without any going over 1 (as they would if I simply scaled by sum). I am currently using scaled up/down probabilities (summing to 1) based on their proportion to the group and then simulating results based on these probabilities, but I'm not sure if this is mathematically sound.

I'm open to other approaches and would love some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: I built a model for predicting the All-NBA teams a few years back. There was 15 possible spots, and they had to be filled by certain positions. The model didn't know that. I simply rank-ordered the probabilities and took the top 15, with those positional caveats. That is a naive approach, but one you can do nonetheless: Take the top 3. I upvoted here because I'm interested in an answer: How can we tell the model to let the outcomes be correlated with one another?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Mark. My current strategy is to assign the top 3 ranks to the top 3 spots as you are doing. Being able to assign probabilities that sum up to my known total would allow me to assign “top 3 shares” in a sense.